# Specific regex test

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to make a specific regex for something like this:

```
(\d{1,3}\/\d{1,3}\/\d{1,3})\-(.*)
```

example:

```
1/2/3-abc
```

It accepts:

- `1/2/3` - capture index 1
- and `abc` - capture index 2

I need from capture index 1 just `123` without '/' characters.

I tried it with positive/ negative lookahead, but it won't work.

Many Thanks

Comment: You can't match non-continuous text within one match operation. Use a `replaceAll` method after matching what you need. Better - with no regex here.

Comment: You need to do a String replace on the match.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve what you need with some string operations:

```js
var s = "1/2/3-abc";
if (s.indexOf("-") > -1) {  // Check if there is a hyphen in the string
    document.write( s.substring(0, s.indexOf("-")).replace(/\//g, ""));
}
```

The `s.indexOf("-")` will find the index of the first `-` character in the input string, and after we get the substring from the start till the `-` (with `s.substring(0, s.indexOf("-"))`), we can remove the `/` symbols with `.replace(/\//g, "")`.

Comment: Question is for JavaScript. :p

Comment: I have been answering Java questions too often today. I have re-written the answer providing JS code.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot extract characters out of an individual match. You need to capture the whole group. After that, you can replace the characters you do not want.

You can extract the group using a matcher or a replacer.

```js
function processMatcher(str) {
  var match = str.match(/(\d{1,3}\/\d{1,3}\/\d{1,3})\-(.*)/);
  return match[1].replace(/[\/]/g, '');
}

function processReplacer(str) {
  return str.replace(/(\d{1,3}\/\d{1,3}\/\d{1,3})\-(.*)/, function(match, p1, p2, offset, string) {
    return p1.replace(/[\/]/g, '');
  });
}

document.body.innerHTML  = 'Matcher: ' + processMatcher('1/2/3-abc') + '</br />';
document.body.innerHTML += 'Replacer: ' + processReplacer('1/2/3-abc');
```